# issues with serializing and deserializing avro data using FlinkKafkaProducer/FlinkKafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am facing some issues while reading/writing Avro data via `FlinkKafkaProducer` / `FlinkKafkaConsumer` through Beam.

It would be great if someone can point to working example of `FlinkKafkaProducer` and `FlinkKafkaConsumer` using Avro schema (NOT using confluent edition of Kafka)

A) BeamKafkaFlinkAvroProducerTest (Producer)

If I use KafkaProducer directly (i.e. call *produceSimpleData*), things are working fine (just for testing). Using `FlinkKafkaProducer` as UnboundedSource (this is what I should do)
(i.e. I call *produceAvroData2*) with the following steps:

1. First, if I use `AvroSerializationSchema schema = new AvroSerializationSchema(Test.class);`

   i.e. essentially using Avro’s `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter`; I face following error:

   ```
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
   at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:580)
   at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:595)
   at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:112)
   at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
   ```
2. Next, if I use `TypeInformationSerializationSchema` (irrespective of AvroCoder in Pipeline), things apparently work fine as Kafka test consumer tool prints the message:

   ```
   java.lang.String{"uname": "Joe", "id": 6}
   ```

B) BeamKafkaFlinkAvroConsumerTest (Consumer)

I understand we should either use `TypeInformationSerializationSchema` in both consumer and producer OR should use `AvroDeserializationSchema` and `AvroSerializationSchema` in Consumer and Producer respectively.

But, irrespective of using `AvroDeserializationSchema` or `TypeInformationSerializationSchema`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: V=null
at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)
at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.<init>(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:39)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap.of(ImmutableBiMap.java:49)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(ImmutableMap.java:70)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getDefaultOutputCoder(CoderRegistry.java:221)
```

---

May be missing something very basic stuff. All code is [here](https://gist.github.com/kaniska/5ceb214193b7604815fb23b74151bd93).